# How to run Erlang nodes?

Tags: erlang

How to create new node? i try some like here 
[how to run this erlang example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101920/how-to-run-this-erlang-example)
and find the same in tutorial 
http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html when i write

> `% erl -name dilbert`

my compiler behaves i forgot '.' at the end.  Of course i try end, result the same.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `erl -name dilbert` is not meant to be typed into the Erlang shell; it's the command you run to start a distributed node instead of plain `erl`.

(If you really want to turn a running node into a distributed node, you can use [net_kernel:start/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#start-1), but I've never had a reason to do that except in tests.)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you can type `erl -name dilbert` in the **terminal**.
In Windows you run it in  **CMD**.